# copy non transparent pixels only to HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-animation

I am writing a colouring game for small children, where I have a black and white image shown on a canvas initially, and as the user moves the drawing tool (mouse) over the canvas, the black and white surface gets over-painted with the colour information from the corresponding coloured image.

In particular, on every mouse move I need to copy a circular area from the coloured image to my canvas. The edge of the circle should be a little blurry to better immitate the qualities of a real drawing tool.

The question is how to accomplish this?

One way I see is to use a clipping region, but this approach does not let me have blurry edges. Or does it?

So I was thinking about using an alpha mask to do that and copy only pixels that correspond to the pixels in the mask that have non zero alpha. Is it feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to have your drawable canvas in front of the coloured image you wish to reveal. (You could use your coloured image as a CSS background image for the canvas.)

Initially have the canvas containing the black and white image with 100% opacity.    Then, when you draw, actually erase the contents of the canvas to show the image behind.

Like this:

```
var pos_x, pos_y, circle_radius;  // initialise these appropriately

context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0, 1.0)";

// And "draw" a circle (actually erase it to reveal the background image)
context.beginPath();
context.arc(pos_x, pos_y, circle_radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
context.fill();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use multiple clipping regions with varying alpha (one dab for each) to mimic the effect you are after. Render the low opacity one first (paste using drawImage) and render the rest after that till you reach alpha=1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using radial gradients that go from an opaque color to a fully transparent one?

Here is a demo from Mozilla. The circles are drawn the way you need. - https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/4_10_canvas_radialgradient.html

Comment: Thanks. Alpha gradients is the way they do it in ActionScript, so yes, I thought about that, I just do not know how to use gradients for copying from an image to a canvas.

Comment: Oh right, I read your question wrong. Sorry. I don't think you can do that with an image. The only way I can think about is to render the circular area to one canvas and draw a white-to-black radial gradient in the `xor` composition mode. Then copy this to the main canvas. It is probably not possible exactly this way but you get the idea.